# Следующая проверка?

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, очередь-проверок

Мне кажется, эти сообщения надо как-то переформулировать чтобы слово "проверка" не повторялось. А то возникает ощущение, что следующей тоже будет проверка на внимательность.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Ну не знаю, лично для меня это логично. Ничто не мешает следующей проверке снова быть проверкой меня. "Следующая проверка" - это проверка любого включая меня

Comment: вот из за этих проверок я и перестал делать проверки. смотришь на предлагаемую проверку - а там, бред-бредовый. И сидишь такой и думаешь, неужели меня за идиота держат? Неужели мне больше нечем заняться.

Comment: Да можно добавить просто слово "Далее"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оригинальная строка [выглядит](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/3036) так:

> This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention. **You passed.**

Убрать слово проверка можно, например, таким вариантом:

> Это всего лишь тест, чтобы оценить вашу внимательность. **Вы прошли его.**

Будет доступно в следующих сборках. Текущая 2023.9.29.43652

Comment: А как же строка с провалом аудита?

Comment: @Зонтик там уже "audit", кстати. Но я тоже использовал "тест" в [переводе](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/1266).

Comment: [Применилось](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duJb9.png)

Answer (score -1):

Я вижу проблему не в том, что следующая проверка — тоже аудит, а в том, что повтор (троекратный, между прочем) режет слух (или глаз?).

Предлагаю такой вариант, ибо проблема осталась:

> Это всего проверка вашей внимательности. Вы прошли **это испытание**.

И на кнопке (по предложению @Aarnihauta):

> Далее

**P.S**: и тоже самое с провалам аудита.

Comment: А может вместо "испытание" лучше тот самый "аудит"?

Comment: Предлагаю посмотреть на [оригинальную строку](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/3036). Это может прояснить ситуацию.

Comment: @wchistow можно и так, но "испытание", по-моему, понятней.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ и как оригинальная строка проясняет ситуацию?

Comment: Например, то что используется слово "test", а не "audit". И фраза, например, могла бы стать примерно такой "Это всего лишь тест. Вы его прошли".